# Error processing resource while generating XML

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I am using mysql_real_escape_string function while inserting the data into MySQL database. I am getting

> "End tag 'test_field' does not match the start tag 'End'. Error
>   processing resource"

while generating the XML. It looks like special characters or less than or greater than symbols causing this problem. Here is my code. Please let me know if there are any suggestions.

Here is PHP code.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * from table1");

header("Content-Type: application/xml");
echo sqlToXml($result, "SalesOrder", "sales");

function sqlToXml($queryResult, $rootElementName, $childElementName)
{

$xmlData = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\" ?>\n"; 
$xmlData .= "<" . $rootElementName . ">";

while($record = mysql_fetch_object($queryResult))
{ 
    $xmlData .= "<" . $childElementName . ">";
    for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($queryResult); $i++)
    { 
        $fieldName = mysql_field_name($queryResult, $i); 
        $xmlData .= "<" . $fieldName . ">";
        if(!empty($record->$fieldName))
            $xmlData .= $record->$fieldName; 
        else
            $xmlData .= "null"; 

        $xmlData .= "</" . $fieldName . ">"; 
    } 

        $detail = mysql_query("SELECT * from table2 WHERE salesordernumber = '".$record->SalesOrderNumber."'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($detail)) { 
   $xmlData .= "<Details>";
   $xmlData .= "<SalesOrderDetailID>" . $row->SalesOrderDetailID . "</SalesOrderDetailID>";
   $xmlData .= "<Name>" . $row->Name . "</Name>";
   $xmlData .= "<CarrierTrackingNumber>" . $row->CarrierTrackingNumber . "</CarrierTrackingNumber>";
   $xmlData .= "</Details>";
}



    $xmlData .= "</" . $childElementName . ">"; 
} 
$xmlData .= "</" . $rootElementName . ">"; 
}
```

Comment: you are not returning anything.Check if that's the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using PHPs [XMLWriter](http://php.net/manual/de/book.xmlwriter.php) for generating the XML. You can easily generate valid XML-files with it and imo it is much more readable:

```
function sqlToXml($queryResult, $rootElementName, $childElementName) {
    $w = new XMLWriter();
    $w->openMemory();
    $w->setIndent(true);
    // use tabs as indents
    $w->setIndentString("   ");
    $w->startDocument("1.0", 'ISO-8859-1');
    $w->startElement($rootElementName);

    while($record = mysql_fetch_object($queryResult)) {
        $w->startElement($childElementName);
        for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($queryResult); $i++) { 
            $fieldName = mysql_field_name($queryResult, $i); 
            $w->startElement($fieldName);
            if(!empty($record->$fieldName)) {
                $w->writeCData($record->$fieldName);
            }
            else {
                $w->writeCData("null");
            }
            $w->endElement(); // $fieldName
        } 
        $w->endElement(); // $childElementName
    } 
    $w->endElement(); // $rootElementName
    $w->endDocument();
    return $w->outputMemory();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I am getting <field_name>
<![CDATA[ test data  ]]> </field_name>. How to remove <![CDATA[ ?

Comment: Why would you like to remove the CDATA-Tag? This was by intention, CDATA does not hurt! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA But if you want to remove it anyway http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xmlwriter-text.php should work.

Comment: TimWolla, The code works. I just modified my PHP code to generate detail table XML. I am just trying to make your code work with detail table. Please see my edited PHP code. Thanks again.

Comment: @nav100 I am sure this is something you can do by yourself by looking at the documentation and my example. StackOverflow is not for getting other users to write your code.

Comment: I have some 100 records to generate XML. It's very slow. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @nav100 No I don't have any ideas besides caching the result for some time.